Movie about travelling into an unseen world
This is a movie about a crew formed by a few people including a woman (who's husband went missing after embarging on a trip to the centre of the earth and never came back) looking for a new world in the centre of the Earth. At some point during their travel they get sucked into a water swirl straight into an unseen world. They see this interesting beach where the mountains were suspended from the sky, everything was different. Going into a jungle they then discover they're not alone and that creatures - half human half dinosaur like, with very sharp claws come looking for them. They get rescued by indigens and brought to a town where the leader of them was exactly the husband who went missing.
On their way back they get some weird blue looking plant with extreme healing powers and the husband knows it's going to be extremely expensive when they make it back on earth.
On their way back, trying to climb a tall hill his back pack with the plants fall and he's going back down to get them.. and he gets caught and killed by one of the creatures from that land and the wife decides not to go back for the backpack filled with the plants.
The remaining crew gets back and no one believes what they have been through so one of the younger guys from the crew comes back as he fell in love with one of the indigen ladies.

An approximate year of release would really help here...

It sounds like an adaptation of Jules Verne's Journey to the Center of the Earth. While there were many of them, I think the 1999 miniseries with Treat Williams is closer to the plot you described: The missing husband turning out to be a leader there, the healing plant and the falling backpack leading to his demise, the half-dinosaur men with sharp claws and the young man who falls in love with an indigenous girl, it's all there. Here's a rather long clip from it:



